# Quiz App: Buttons in javascript are not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

Currently I'm working on a quiz in multiple choice format. However, when I click on a button, it simply doesn't work!

Here's the full code of my mini quiz
https://github.com/selvabalasingam/TypeQuiz/blob/master/js/app.js

But I'm sure that the problem lies between lines 89-103 (I've pasted a portion of this code below)

```
$('button.choice').click(function(e) {
    var choice = $(e.target).text();
    var question = quiz.getCurrentQuestion(); 
    // check if the answer is right and update question number and score
    if (Question.answer == choice) {
        getTotalCorrect = $('.questionCount').text(getTotalCorrect+1); 
        getScore = $('.scorePercentage').text(getScore);
    }
    else {
        getTotalCorrect = $('.questionCount').text(getTotalCorrect+0); 
        getScore = $('.scorePercentage').text(getScore);
    }
    // then go to the next question
    getNextQuestion();
});
```

Can anyone tell what the problem is? Is there a way I could fix this?

Comment: Does the console show any errors?

Comment: One reason why a button in javascript won't work is probably because of a semantic error. Did you get any errors in the console log?

Comment: I updated my code but now after I answer my first question my next question isn't appearing. I did try looking into the console - but I don't see any errors. 

http://selvabalasingam.github.io/TypeQuiz/#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at the console, you'll see that `getTotalCorrect` is `undefined`. This is because `getTotalCorrect` is a method attached to the scope of the `quiz` object, but you're trying to access it globally.

You can change this:

```
if (Question.answer == choice) {
    getTotalCorrect = $('.questionCount').text(getTotalCorrect+1); 
    getScore = $('.scorePercentage').text(getScore);
}
else {
    getTotalCorrect = $('.questionCount').text(getTotalCorrect+0); 
    getScore = $('.scorePercentage').text(getScore);
}
getNextQuestion();
```

to:

```
question.answer = choice;    // pass the user's choice to the question object
$('.questionCount').text(quiz.getTotalCorrect());
$('.scorePercentage').text(quiz.getScore());
quiz.getNextQuestion();    // load the next question
renderText(quiz.getCurrentQuestion());    // render the new font
```

It looks like `renderText` would indefinitely call itself:

```
var renderText = function(question) {
    $('.text').css('font-family', question.correctChoice);
    renderText(quiz.getCurrentQuestion());   // infinite recursion call
};
```

Instead, call renderText when the page loads, like so:

```
var renderText = function(question) {
    $('.text').css('font-family', question.correctChoice);
};

renderText(quiz.getCurrentQuestion());
```

Comment: Thank you so much Stiliyan!!! I made this correction on my code and now I see the score show up but it doesn't move on to the next question, so I'll have to figure it out. Wish I could rep you but I'm a newbie!

Comment: You're welcome, Selva, and good luck - this is very close!! Looks like you'll have to fix the infinite recursion in `renderText`, and then call it when the quiz is initialized, and an answer is selected. I updated my answer with some details. You can also probably group all display functionality into a new `Quiz.prototype` method called `displayCurrentQuestion`

Answer (score 1):

Change

`getTotalCorrect = $('.questionCount').text(getTotalCorrect+1);`

to

`getTotalCorrect = $('.questionCount').text(quiz.getTotalCorrect+1);`

Answer (score 0):

You never set your `Question.answer` value. This value is sometimes a function and sometimes an object. You should probably rename `Question.answer` (as a function to `Question.setAnswer`.

[from this gist](https://github.com/selvabalasingam/TypeQuiz/blob/master/js/app.js#L45-L48)

```
Question.prototype = {
    setAnswer: function(choice) {
        this.answer = choice;
    },
}
```

That being said,  `Question.answer`/`Question.setAnswer` is never called, instead you want to look directly at `Question.correctChoice`.

```
   if (Question.correctChoice == choice) {
        getTotalCorrect = $('.questionCount').text(getTotalCorrect+1); 
        getScore = $('.scorePercentage').text(getScore);
    }
    else {
        getTotalCorrect = $('.questionCount').text(getTotalCorrect+0); 
        getScore = $('.scorePercentage').text(getScore);
    }
```